# Removing an element from a list between <br/> tags - PYTHON

Tags: python, list, split

I am scraping a site and the results are formatted under one ID. The output varies with the number of breaks in the results. I have a pattern built that will pull the company name, address, city/state, and phone number.

I initially targeted removing any element with 'SUITE' in it, but some of the addresses have 'SUITE' in the same lane as the actual address and throw off the pattern. Is there a way I can check to see if there are any values before the string 'SUITE' and if not, remove it?

```
for r in list(result_list):
    if '<br/>' in r:
        result_list.remove(r)
    else:
        if 'dba' in r:
            result_list.remove(r)
        else:
            if 'SUITE' in r:
                result_list.remove(r)
            else:
                clean_list.append(r)
```

EXAMPLE 1:

```
1066915 #<- License
BROOKFIELD SOCAL LAND CONSTRUCTORS LLC #<- Business Name (index 0)
<br/>
12265 EL CAMINO REAL #<- Address (index 1)
<br/>
SUITE 180 #<- NOT NEEDED
<br/>
SAN DIEGO, CA 92130 #<- City/State (index 2)
<br/>
Business Phone Number:(714) 427-6868 #<- Phone (index 3)
<br/>
<br/>
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
1066919
J G CONST CORP #<- company name (index 0) or every 4th element
<br/>
dba J G CONSTRUCTION CORP #<- removed
<br/>
<br/>
449 W FOOTHILL BLVD SUITE #276 #< -Address would be removed with current
<br/>
GLENDORA, CA 91741 #<- City/State (index 2)
<br/>
Business Phone Number:(626) 460-1014 #<- Phone (index 3)
<br/>
<br/>
```

My thoughts are if there is a way to check if there is a space or character one or two elements ahead of the s in suite, it shouldn't be removed.

Comment: You are modifying `result_list` while iterating over it, always a bad idea. Does your problem magically disappear when you don't do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand. I have heard its bad practice before but i'm not familiar with another method of how to modify a list multiple times

Comment: @usr2564301. The problem has nothing to do with that, but the advice is still good.

Comment: @sjuice10. Do you know about `elif`. And better yet, `or`?

Comment: I do not. I will do some research

Comment: I mention this because I noticed that you have a habit of not selecting answers. Selecting an answer removes your question from the unanswered queue, and gives the folks that help you some reputation points (and yourself too).

Comment: You can always go to your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13680652/sjuice10?tab=questions) page to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer the question, let me present a slightly more elegant way to write your original conditional statement using [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#elif) instead of nested [`else-if`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements):

```
if '<br/>' in r:
    result_list.remove(r)
elif 'dba' in r:
    result_list.remove(r)
elif 'SUITE' in r:
    result_list.remove(r)
else:
    clean_list.append(r)
```

Given that you want to do the same thing in every case, you can use the [`or`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) operator to write

```
if '<br/>' in r or 'dba' in r or 'SUITE' in r:
    result_list.remove(r)
else:
    clean_list.append(r)
```

However, you really should not be modifying the list that you are iterating over. Because list iterators work by index, you are actually unintentionally skipping elements every time you do. The good news is that you don't need to modify `result_list` at all: all you care about is what ends up in `clean_list`. Also, you don't need to make something into a list to iterate over it with [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

```
for r in result_list:
    if not ('<br/>' in r or 'dba' in r or 'SUITE' in r):
        clean_list.append(r)
```

Finally, to solve your actual problem with the string containing `SUITE`, you can use [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to get the *index*, and then subset based on that:

```
for r in result_list:
    index = r.find('SUITE')
    if index == 0 or (index > 0 and r[index - 1].isspace()):
        addr = r[:index].rstrip()
        if addr:
            clean_list.append(addr)
    elif not ('<br/>' in r or 'dba' in r):
        clean_list.append(r)
```